# EMA function works on R dataframe, but fails on spark dataframe - Sparklyr

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, sparklyr

I am relatively new to R  as well as to Spark.
I am writing a function to calculate the exponential moving average for a set of data. I am using the sparklyr package to work on the Databricks Spark platform.

I have written a function that works on a normal R dataframe. However, it is failing when applied to a Spark dataframe.

I am currently not interested in the correctness of the values (I am using dummy values - for eg. init = 10 is arbitrary). I'm more interested in getting this working on a Spark dataframe

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks") 

set.seed(21)
#data
x <- rnorm(1e4)
#data in a dataframe
x_df <- data.frame(x)
#data in a Spark dataframe
x_sprk <- copy_to(sc, x_df, name ="x_sql", overwrite = TRUE)

#function to calculate Exponential moving average

ewma_filter <- function (df, ratio = 0.9) {
  mutate(df, ema = c(stats::filter(x * ratio, 1 - ratio, "recursive", init = 10)))
}
```

When I run this function on a R dataframe, it works fine

```
y_df <- x_df %>% ewma_filter()
```

Output:

```
                 x           ema
1     0.6785634656  1.6107071191
2    -0.8519017349 -0.6056408495
3    -0.0362643838 -0.0932020304
4     0.2422350575  0.2086913487
5    -1.0401144499 -0.9152338701
6     1.4521621543  1.2154225519
7    -0.8531140006 -0.6462603453
8     0.4779933902  0.3655680167
9     1.0719294487  1.0012933055
10   -0.4115495580 -0.2702652716
11    2.4152301588  2.1466806157
12   -0.1045401223  0.1205819515
13   -0.1632591646 -0.1348750530
14   -2.1441820131 -1.9432513170
15    0.4672471535  0.2261973065
16    0.9362099384  0.8652086752
17    0.6494043831  0.6709848123
18    2.5609202716  2.3719267257
```

But when I try it on Spark dataframe, i do not get the intended output:

```
y_sprk <- x_sprk %>% ewma_filter()
```

Output:

```
         x ema            

 1  0.679  
 2 -0.852  
 3 -0.0363 
 4  0.242  
 5 -1.04   
 6  1.45   
 7 -0.853  
 8  0.478  
 9  1.07   
10 -0.412  
# … with more rows
```

I tried using spark_apply():

```
y_sprk <- spark_apply(x_sprk, ewma_filter, columns = list(x = "numeric", ema = "numeric"))
```

I get the below error:

```
Error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 115.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 115.0 (TID 8623, 10.139.64.6, executor 0): java.lang.Exception: sparklyr worker rscript failure with status 255, check worker logs for details.
    at sparklyr.Rscript.init(rscript.scala:106)
    at sparklyr.WorkerApply$$anon$2.run(workerapply.scala:116)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:204)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: sparklyr worker rscript failure with status 255, check worker logs for details.
    at sparklyr.Rscript.init(rscript.scala:106)
    at sparklyr.WorkerApply$$anon$2.run(workerapply.scala:116)
```

I would be grateful if you could help to debug this and get this working on a spark dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close!  `spark_apply()` works on each partition of a Spark DataFrame by default, which works well for what you are trying to do.  The error message you got doesn't tell you too much - to really see what happened you actually have to look in the logs for the worker nodes, in `stdout`.  On Databricks you can find this in the Clusters UI under 'Spark UI - Master', and then by drilling into the worker nodes.

For your code, the error message was actually `19/11/10 19:38:25 ERROR sparklyr: RScript (2719) terminated unexpectedly: could not find function "mutate"`

It might seem odd that `mutate` can't be found, but the way these UDFs work is that an R process is created on the worker nodes, and for the function to work all of the code/libraries need to be available on those nodes as well.  Since you are running on Databricks and `dplyr` in included in the Databricks Runtime, it is available on all of the worker nodes.  You just need to reference the namespace or load the full library:

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stats)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks") 

# Create R dataframe
set.seed(21)
x <- rnorm(1e4)
x_df <- data.frame(x)

# Push R dataframe to Spark
x_sprk <- copy_to(sc, x_df, name ="x_sql", overwrite = TRUE)

# Distribute the R code across each partition
spark_apply(x_sprk, function(x) {

  # Define moving average function and reference dplyr explicitly
  ewma_filter <- function (df, ratio = 0.9) {
  dplyr::mutate(df, ema = c(stats::filter(x * ratio, 1 - ratio, "recursive", init = 10)))
  }

  # Apply it to each partition of the Spark DF
  ewma_filter(x)
})
```

These are the results of this call to `spark_apply()`:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
          x      ema
      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1  0.793    1.71   
 2  0.522    0.641  
 3  1.75     1.64   
 4 -1.27    -0.981  
 5  2.20     1.88   
 6  0.433    0.578  
 7 -1.57    -1.36   
 8 -0.935   -0.977  
 9  0.0635  -0.0406 
10 -0.00239 -0.00621
# … with more rows
```

This is also covered in the [R User Guide for Databricks](https://github.com/marygracemoesta/R-User-Guide#r-on-databricks-a-user-guide).

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks a lot. That solved the above issue!
However, this was on the dummy data that i generated using the rnorm function.

But when I try to apply this on the actual data I'm working with (with the same structure as the dummy data), it's throwing a null.pointer exception.

When I investigated further, i found that the null.pointer exception at the time of reading the data.
Is this a known error?

I know I am being vague. Apologies. I'll try to post this as a separate question and add the link here.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805009/spark-apply-works-on-one-dataset-but-fails-on-another-both-datasets-are-of-sam