# spark_apply works on one dataset, but fails on another (both datasets are of same type and structure)

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, sparklyr

I am working with sparklyr on databricks.

The issue i am facing is that spark_apply() is throwing an error, when i run it on one dataset, but works fine when it is run on another dataset (of same structure and type). Am i missing something?
The error message (reproduced) doesnt help much.

Simple spark_apply function below:

```
 spark_apply(hr2, function(y) y*2)
```

Schema and class of hr2

```
$LITRES
$LITRES$name
[1] "LITRES"

$LITRES$type
[1] "DoubleType"


class(hr2)
[1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"
```

Error:

```
Error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 6835.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 6835.0 (TID 132104, 10.139.64.8, executor 1): java.lang.Exception: sparklyr worker rscript failure with status 255, check worker logs for details.
    at sparklyr.Rscript.init(rscript.scala:106)
    at sparklyr.WorkerApply$$anon$2.run(workerapply.scala:116)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2355)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2343)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2342)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2574)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2510)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2240)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollectResult(limit.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectResult(Dataset.scala:2828)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3440)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:3419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withAction(Dataset.scala:3419)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:204)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor398.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: sparklyr worker rscript failure with status 255, check worker logs for details.
    at sparklyr.Rscript.init(rscript.scala:106)
    at sparklyr.WorkerApply$$anon$2.run(workerapply.scala:116)

In addition: Warning messages:
1: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `SUM(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning 
2: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
Use `SUM(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning
```

Error log of the worker node:

```
19/11/11 16:12:30 INFO sparklyr: Worker (1805) is starting R process
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is starting 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is connecting to backend using port 40277 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) accepted connection
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 40277
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is querying ports from backend using port 40277 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) received command 0
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) found requested session matches current session
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) is creating backend and allocating system resources
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) is using port 0 for backend channel
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) created the backend
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: Session (1805) is waiting for r process to end
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) found redirect gateway port 40277 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is connected to backend 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is connecting to backend session 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is connected to backend session 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) created connection 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) is connected 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) retrieved worker context id 0 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) retrieved worker context 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) using bundle name packages.tar 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) using bundle path /databricks/spark/work/app-20191111144228-0000/1/packages.tar 
19/11/11 16:12:31 INFO sparklyr: RScript (1805) updated .libPaths with bundle packages 
19/11/11 16:12:31 ERROR sparklyr: RScript (1805) terminated unexpectedly: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.getTaskInputMetrics$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.beginUpdateFilesystemSQLMetrics$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:638)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at sparklyr.WorkerContext.getSourceArray(workercontext.scala:47)
    at sparklyr.WorkerContext.getSourceArrayLength(workercontext.scala:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The same code works without errors when applied on a dummy dataset created as below:

```
# Create R dataframe
set.seed(21)
x <- rnorm(1e4)
x_df <- data.frame(x)
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks") 
x_sprk <- copy_to(sc, x_df, name ="x_sql", overwrite = TRUE)
```

The schema and class of x_sprk is:

```
sdf_schema(x_sprk)
$PREV_VAL
$PREV_VAL$name
[1] "PREV_VAL"

$PREV_VAL$type
[1] "DoubleType"


class(x_sprk)
[1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"
```

Function in  question. same as earlier, but applied to x_sprk

```
spark_apply(x_sprk, function(y) y*2)
```

As mentioned, spark_apply works fine for the second dataset.

Could you please help me with what i need to take care of in the first dataset which is causing the error message?
The datasets dont have any missing values.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide a sample of the data so I can test on this?  It's hard to say what might be the problem without that.

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks for coming back on this. Yes, i agree, i had not provided enough for you to debug. I was trying to find a way to provide sample data, but I didnt know how to do that without affecting the integrity of the problem itself.
Anyway, I have narrowed down this problem to the fact that spark_apply() is failing when applied to sparklyr dataframes created from an sql table using sdf_sql(). 
I dont know if this is an issue with sparklyr or is it with databricks. I've raised this with databricks separately. Will update when I hear back from them.

Comment: Try changing the input to spark apply then.  You should be able to find an approach that way.